# updatePhoneNumber failed: First argument "phoneCredential" must be a valid phone credential

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to updatePhoneNumber and keep getting the following error above. Looking at the docs I was under the impressing this is a method?

Js:

```
user.updatePhoneNumber({
  phoneNumber: "+15618104444",
});
```

I tried setting this in the updateProfile Method as well and still no luck.

```
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: displayName,
  photoURL: photoURL,
  phoneNumber: "+15618104444"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updatePhoneNumber requires a phone credential since the phone number needs to be verified by SMS.

```
// 'recaptcha-container' is the ID of an element in the DOM.
var applicationVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
    'recaptcha-container');
var provider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
provider.verifyPhoneNumber('+16505550101', applicationVerifier)
    .then(function(verificationId) {
      var verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification ' +
          'code that was sent to your mobile device.');
      return firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId,
          verificationCode);
    })
    .then(function(phoneCredential) {
      return user.updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential);
    });
```