# How to add or update phone_number in Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a phone number when a user is signing up using Firebase Auth. I am using this method:

```
user = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('myemail@email.com', 'password').catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

And I am trying to update mobile number during the signup process using:

```
if(user){
  user.updatePhoneNumber("+91999999999")
}
```

I am getting error:

```
updatePhoneNumber failed: First argument "phoneCredential" must be a valid phone credential.
```

I know it needs to be a valid phone number and according to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780653/updatephonenumber-failed-first-argument-phonecredential-must-be-a-valid-phone) we need to verify phone number to update.

So my question is I need to create a signup form where I am getting phone email and PWD.

I want to save phone number and verify the number later. Is there any way we can update phone number during signup.

Using this code I can update phone_number in firebase admin:

```
user = auth.create_user(
    email='user@example.com',
    email_verified=False,
    phone_number='+15555550100',
    password='secretPassword',
    display_name='John Doe',
    photo_url='http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled=False)
```

Why there is no function like this in web signup.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set a phone number for a user without signing them in with/verifying that number. You will have to [sign in the user with phone authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) too, and then [link the two providers together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).

If you don't want to sign the user in with their phone number, but merely want to store that number, you will have to do so outside of Firebase Authentication's built-in phone number provider.

Comment: auth.create_user using this command from firebase admin I can store phone_number why firebase is not flexible. Auth module should include customization.

Comment: It's a valid feature request, so I suggest you file it here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/